# почему console.log(res) срабатывает 5 раз подряд

Tags: javascript

если изменит имена в местах * или ** срабатывает один раз

пытался разобраться мозг попал в рекурсию

```
let fact = function f(n){
  return (n!== 1)? fact(n-1) * n : n //*
}
function decorRes(func){
  return function(a) {
    let res = func(a)
    console.log(res);
    return res
  }
}

fact = decorRes(fact) //**

fact(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы переопределяете переменную `fact`, и на момент вызова она содержит `decorRes`

```
const fact = function f(n){
  return (n!== 1)? fact(n-1) * n : n //*
}
function decorRes(func){
  return function(a) {
    const res = func(a)
    console.log(res);
    return res
  }
}

const bar = decorRes(fact) //**

bar(5)
```

или

```
let fact = function f(n){
  // вызываем функцию
  // а не переменную содержащую функцию
  return (n!== 1)? f(n-1) * n : n  
}
function decorRes(func){
  return function(a) {
    let res = func(a)
    console.log(res);
    return res
  }
}

fact = decorRes(fact) //**

fact(5)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ но можно по подробнее bar тоже на момент вызова содержит decores или нет?

Comment: @Armen, Да, но в вашем случае на момент вызова f функция ссылается не на саму себя а на переменную в которой содержится она, когда вы модифицируете вызов и функция меняет свое поведение

Comment: все равно не понял но спасибо попробую как нить разобраться  либо при рекурсии всегда использовать NFE чтобы этим вопросом не задаваться)